# IBM SPSS Statistics Stuck at sign in page

Tags: spss

I have installed the latest version of IBM SPSS statistic and it is stuck at sign-in step and not moving forward.

I tried changing my network connection and reinstalling it still it is not working.I have Windows 11 laptop with 16 GB RAM.